# How to create menu like on the picture? CSS style

Tags: html, css

[image]

How to create menu like on the picture?

For now I have:

```
<div id="nav">
   <nav class="top-nav">
      <div class="shell">
         <a href="#" class="nav-btn">HOMEPAGE<span></span></a>
         <span class="top-nav-shadow"></span>
         <ul>
            <li class="active"><span><a href="#">home</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">services</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">projects</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">solutions</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">jobs</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">blog</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="#">contacts</a></span></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </nav>
</div>
```

And my css for div nav:

```
     #nav{
         background-color: transparent;
         padding: 0em 0em 0em 2em;
         white-space: nowrap;
         list-style: none outside none;
         margin: 0px;
         height: auto;
         line-height: normal;
     }
```

How to style this? I'm newbie

Comment: Show us your attempts please.

Answer (score 2):

From your picture i think you are looking for a way to make `Tabs` not a menu..

The best thing you can use i think is [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

From that link you can check how to make it using simple html and the jQueryUI css.

If you want to use only css and html kindly check this

[How to make a simple tabbed menu with CSS and HTML](http://mihaifrentiu.com/how-to-make-a-simple-tabbed-menu)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a few js to do it.

Here is an example which doesn't require any framework, and fit to your needs (using jQuery) :

```js
$('#tab-nav > li').click(function(e) {
    // get new active pane id
    var idPane = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href').substring(1);
    // change active nav
    $('#tab-nav > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // change active pane
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
    $('#'+idPane).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.clear { display: block; clear: both; height: 0px; }

#container {
    position: relative;
    color: #497188;
}
#tab-nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
#tab-nav > li { 
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #497188;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #497188;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    margin: 0 2px -1px;
    float: left;
}
#tab-nav > li a {
    color: #497188;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#tab-nav > li.active,
#tab-content {
    background: #DEE7EC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DEE7EC;
}
#tab-content {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #497188;
    z-index: 10;
}
.tab-pane {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 3px;
}
.tab-pane.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <ul id="tab-nav">
        <li class="active"><span><a href="#home">home</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#services">services</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#projects">projects</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#solutions">solutions</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#jobs">jobs</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#blog">blog</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#contacts">contacts</a></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane active">home</div>
        <div id="services" class="tab-pane">services</div>
        <div id="projects" class="tab-pane">projects</div>
        <div id="solutions" class="tab-pane">solutions</div>
        <div id="jobs" class="tab-pane">jobs</div>
        <div id="blog" class="tab-pane">blog</div>
        <div id="contacts" class="tab-pane">contacts</div>
        <p class="clear">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an example. 
Please have a look at it.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3g9BN/4/)**

- The main concept this is positioning the `li` tags on `ul`.
- Giving `bottom: -1px` to the `li` tags to let them come on the border of the `ul`.
- If you give `li` border-bottom then it looks like border of `ul`.

I hope you can create your own styling by referring this (but not copying the code).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efKw5/)** showing the styles you want.

- The `LI` tags are floated left, and `overflow: hidden;` is set on the parent `UL` tag to [contain the floats](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/).
- The entire `UL` tag is shifted down `position: relative; margin-bottom: -1px;` over the top of the element below it. The 1 pixel borders under the `A` tags give the illusion that the tab is part of the element below. The `border-bottom-color` on the active tab is set to match the background color of the content area.
- The `A` tags are set as `display: block;` so that they can be given a `min-width`, `text-align: center;` and vertical `padding`
- I also put a small `border-radius` on the `A` tags for flair :-p This can be removed if you don't want it.

I'm assuming the class `.active` will be changed by code running on your server. If not, the JS listed in several of the above answers will change the class when a tab is clicked. Some of the answers only change the class on the tab (which isn't really what you want…), so look at the libraries instead (however, the CSS will need to be modified accordingly as most JS tab libraries require a specific HTML structure). If you need further details, please leave a comment below.